# Should using "any" be avoided when optimising code in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, generics, existential-type

I was reading the differences between using `some` and `any` and I often read that using `any` causes performance issues. The authors suggest *always* using `some` unless using `any` is *absolutely* necessary.

I encountered a situation where applying this rule of "avoid using existential types if possible" made my code look strange. Consider the following example:

```swift
protocol DogDelegate {
    func didBark()
    func willBark()
}

struct Dog<D: DogDelegate> {
    var delegate: D?  // << Making this `(any DogDelegate)?` would look so much better

    func bark() {
        delegate?.willBark()
        print("Woof!")
        delegate?.didBark()
    }
}
```

In my app, I have a delegate-like property which allows optional customisation of a function. It sort of allows the caller to "modify" the barking a little bit.

If I wanted to make my code as fast as possible, would using generics be preferred in this case? Or is the performance drawback so small that even if I had a million Dogs in an array while using `any` it wouldn't cause a significant performance drop?

Comment: I certainly wouldn't use a generic simply to avoid `any DogDelegate?`

Comment: @Paulw11 Wouldn't it cause a performance drop? If you had a million dogs and you made all of them bark at once, wouldn't that be significantly slower than if you had used a generic?

Comment: Rather than being terrified by *some* source why don't you prove the statement? Xcode offers all tools to do that. But in a strong typed language like Swift it's good practice to basically prefer always `some` over `any`.

Comment: @vadian Im not sure what u mean by “prove the statement”. If you’re talking about the performance thing then I have no clue how to prove it myself except for citing articles that say so. Also, would you prefer using generics for the `Dog` struct I’ve shown in the example instead of `any`? Just curious

Comment: There is some performance impact of the need to "unbox" `any DogDelegate` vs having a concrete type at compile time via a generic, however, my gut feel is that this is not likely to be significant.  If you have a performance problem and you use the time profiler instrument and it reveals that the `any` is causing a performance issue, then you can address it.  To me, having a class be generic on its delegate is just awkward.

Comment: @rayaantaneja - Re “prove the statement”, the suggestion is that you should benchmark the actual performance for both implementations for a practical, real-world scenario (not a theoretical million barking dogs) and see if (a) the difference is even observable; and if so, (b) whether the performance difference is substantial enough to warrant the sacrifice in code quality. But, in general, we avoid “premature optimization” in the vast majority of cases, unless real-world benchmarks demonstrate that the performance difference is material.

Comment: @Rob In my app, the array is likely to get very big. However, I'll test it out and post the results by editing the question. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:** for parameters to a method, prefer taking `some` over `any` as there's no downside or loss of generality; for property, there are definitely applications to sticking with `any` and the impetus to switch is context-dependent and subject to real-world measurement to offset the change in the code.

---

To understand why you might want to use `some Protocol` over `any Protocol`, or vice versa, it helps to understand what `any` and `some` mean under the hood.

By way of analogy, given that you have a protocol `P`, you can imagine `any P` and `some P` as being two different types of boxes:

1. `any P` is an opaque box, which can hold inside of it anything that looks like a `P`. Because it's opaque, you can't quite tell what's inside unless you walk over to it and open it up, to inspect the contents (but on the upside, you can also swap out the contents without anyone noticing!)
2. `some P`, on the other hand, is a transparent (almost *imaginary*) box which can hold only one specific type of `P`-shaped item at a time, with the benefit that you can see what's actually inside the box from across the room — no need to inspect it directly (downside: you can't change what's inside without changing the shape of the box, too)

In many ways, working with these two types of boxes is pretty similar: at the end of the day, they're both meant to hold something that looks like a `P`, and that's their main purpose. The difference between them is the transparency.

---

As boxes, there are two main places that `any` and `some` can be used:

1. As parameters to methods
2. As stored values / properties

In the case of (1), you're looking at the difference between

```swift
func ƒ1(_ p: any P) {
    // Do `P` type things with `p`.
}
```

and

```swift
func ƒ2(_ p: some P) {
    // Do `P` type things with `p`.
}
```

The way an individual value gets used within `ƒ1` and `ƒ2` is *identical*, with no discernible effect to the user of `p`. (Though there is an effective difference, which I'll get to below.)

In the case of (2), there *are* significant differences between holding on to an `any P` and a `some P`:

1. Storing `some P` requires you to make the outer type generic. This can add a lot of additional code to accommodate, and requires all consumers of the type to then also deal with a generic type, possibly propagating that genericity upwards too
2. You cannot store different types of `P` values inside of `some P`, meaning that you may not be able to reassign the property and must instead re-instantiate an entire new value altogether (e.g., in your example, a brand new `Dog<D>` for every different type of `D` delegate)

### So, why use one over the other?

1. As a *parameter*, there's little reason to take `any P` over `some P` these days. Prior to [SE-0352 Implicitly Opened Existentials](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0352-implicit-open-existentials.md), it used to be that the world of existentials (`any P`) and generics (`some P`) were very different, and entirely separate: if you had an existential type, you couldn't, for example, use it to call a generic method. Both existentials and generics were "viral" in a sense: if you had an existential type, you couldn't use it with generic methods, which meant you'd need to write methods which took existentials; and if you wanted to write methods which took advantage of generics, you had to then propagate genericity "upwards" to preserve the types everywhere

   No longer. With SE-0352, you can now pass an existential to a generic method, and Swift will "open" the existential box for you, to give you access to the real type in a way that a generic method can accept. Because of this, there's now little reason to *not* write generic methods, because they can accept both existentials and non-existentials
2. As a *property*, there's absolutely a reason to prefer `any P` over `some P` in at least one case: your property needs to be able to hold one of multiple types of `P`s, and you don't know which at compile time. This is the primary reason for existentials to exist: they are an abstraction over the general concept of `P`, and are general enough to be able to hold *any* `P` inside of them

   Your delegate example is exactly a case where you likely *would* want to write `any DogDelegate`: `Dog` *doesn't* actually care what the actual type of `delegate` is, just that it can do `DogDelegate` things. It makes life significantly easier to be able to assign one of several different `DogDelegate` objects to your `Dog`, without having to make any changes to `Dog` itself

Typically, the switch from `any` to `some` in the case of (1) just requires replacing the keyword; in the case of (2), there's a significant difference between them, and you need to evaluate what makes sense for your code in context.

### Performance

To get a bit more technical, there are two performance characteristics of `any` and `some` to keep in mind, given the choices above:

1. When people refer to existential "boxes", they are literally referring to an object in memory which holds inside of it a reference to some other value of type `P`. The "box" is a reified value, which can respond to methods by passing them along to the underlying value — at the *slight* cost of additional indirection to do so. (e.g., an additional pointer access)

   The reason I referred to `some P` as an *imaginary* box above is that in reality, there *is* no box: `some` is a compile-time concept exclusively. `some` is a slightly nicer spelling for generics, such that

   ```swift
   func f<T: P>(_ p: T) { ... }
   ```

   and

   ```swift
   func g(_ p: some P) { ... }
   ```

   are identical. In `f`, you can tell that you can actually "see" the effective type `T` the method is being called with, whereas in `g` the actual type is slightly obscured, in case you don't really care about it. (It's made a bit more "opaque", and in fact, these are known as [opaque parameter types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0341-opaque-parameters.md) — matching [opaque result types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0244-opaque-result-types.md))

   Because of this, `some P` has *no* overhead at all, because the compiler actually knows at *compile time* what the effective type really is: it's only obscured from you, the developer
2. And because of this (that the compiler sees through `some` types), a generic method can be optimized more thoroughly by the compiler than one which takes an existential. How this manifests in practice depends very heavily on what the method actually does, so it's hard to generalize, but in some cases, the optimization may be significant

> I often read that using any causes performance issues. The authors suggest always using `some` unless using `any` is *absolutely* necessary.

In practice, it's easy for folks to get a bit carried away with suggestions like this; you absolutely should not be terrified of using existential types, especially not to the point of rewriting your codebase to eliminate all `any`s. Nothing has effectively *changed* with the labeling of `any` and `some`, just made more explicit as to what the code might be doing — and we've used existentials just fine in Swift for a long time!

The cost of using an existential in code over a generic type is likely *marginal*: the cost of a pointer indirection relative to what your program is doing is *vanishingly* small, but it is technically there. In *some* cases, there may be a performance benefit to switching over to a generic type because of more thorough compiler optimizations, but that's case-by-case basis territory.

The main reason folks recommend switching over is that in many cases, you can simply swap `any` to `some` with no further work necessary, and not doing so leaves some amount of "free performance" on the table. What and how you make such changes is up to you — but the reason the comments above all recommend benchmarking is to show you that you can find out yourself, for your specific application, whether this makes any **meaningful** difference or not. I highly suspect that for the vast majority of applications out there, the difference is non-existent.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a wonderful answer. I would like clarification on one thing before I accept this answer. In my code, the "delegate-like" property is a constant. Thus, **I don't require the capability of switching it for other types seamlessly**. From what I understand, if the requirement to switch the delegate isn't there, then there is no reason to use existentials (except for personal preference / ease of not dealing with generics). Am I right?

Comment: @rayaantaneja That’s correct. If you don’t need the dynamic qualities of `any` in this case, then you can indeed use generics. Just consider that (1) it’s pretty uncommon to see generics used in such an application, and it can be confusing/unexpected for readers; and (2) if this requirement changes in the future, you may need to refactor significant amounts of code to accommodate the change. The cost may be higher than you expect for effectively little-to-no benefit.